# How to make Information output to initially appear collapsed?

Tags: version-12, information-function

If I say use the following command:

```
Information["EntityFramework`*"]
```

It prints all the matching function from the required context but there is a option  to collapse it. Similarly querying multiple contexts.

```
Information["*`*Entity*"]
```

produces result that is grouped by the contexts they are from with a option to collapse each separately.

Is there an option I can give to `Information` that will allow all the grouped contexts to appear collapse on initial execution so they don't clutter the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a trick to force that (sadly there is no and can be no option by how this function is written):

```
Information; (* activate the autoloader *)
DownValues[System`InformationDump`labeledgridwithopener] =
  DownValues[System`InformationDump`labeledgridwithopener] /.

   DynamicModuleBox[{Typeset`open$$ = True}, a___] :>
    DynamicModuleBox[{Typeset`open$$ = TrueQ@Typeset`$InformationGridOpen}, 
     a];
```

Now if `` Typeset`$InformationGridOpen `` is `True` it displays automatically opened and otherwise it's closed:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I was just about to post the same thing, more or less. :)

Comment: @MichaelE2 if you want the 30 rep this will probably bring I can delete and you can post :)

Comment: No problem. We almost tied, that's all. It's happened before. Sometimes even, I'm first. :)  ``TrueQ@Typeset`$InformationGridOpen`` is a nice touch, btw.

Comment: Note: You need to load/initialize the `Information[]` support code before you can change the `DownValues` of `labeledgridwithopener`. Evaluating `Information` is sufficient it seems.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I'm sure there's some autoload on it. Didn't know that.

Comment: All of you found the working solution and now i am confused as to whose answer I should accept. @kglr answer waits for the output of the `Information` and modify the boxes while your actually introduces an input $ variable to the Downvalue of some context `Information` relies on to produce the boxes. I like your solution more since I can keep relying on the same builtin variable `Information` and so no changes anywhere in the existing code.

Comment: I have upvoted both but will accept yours. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Until someone discovers the magic undocumented option that controls the initial states of `Opener`s, you can process the boxes to modify the initializations of `DynamicModule`s  in information grid:

```
collapse = RawBoxes @ Replace[ToBoxes[#], 
   HoldPattern[Typeset`open$$ = _] :>  (Typeset`open$$ = False), All] &;
   
Information["*`*Entity"] // collapse
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is can be no magic undocumented option as ``System`InformationDump`labeledgridwithopener`` has its `$$opener = True` default state hardcoded in. If you redefine that function, though, it'll work clean.

Comment: ``MakeBoxes[#, StandardForm] &@Information["Plot*"]; (* initialize *)
DownValues[System`InformationDump`labeledgridwithopener] = 
 DownValues[System`InformationDump`labeledgridwithopener] /. 
  HoldPattern[{Typeset`open$$ = _}] :> {Typeset`open$$ = False}`` makes it "permanent" (i.e. for the session).